# Cannot insert into hsql database with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

My problem is,I trying add one record into HSQL Database and I can't. 
Really don't know what is wrong also how to fix this.All of this is really annyoing me,cuz it's simply example and I can't run this.

At the begining I run HSQLDB server with this command :

```
 java -cp ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:mydb --dbname.0 xdb
```

Everythink is ok,server is running. 
Now I'm trying add one record in database in this way :

```
private static void fun() {    

    Configuration configuration;
    configuration = new Configuration().addResource("hibernate.cfg.xml");

    configuration.configure();

    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(); 
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction(); 

    Employee employee = new Employee();  
    employee.setName("Please"); 
    employee.setSurname("work !"); 
    employee.setEmployeeType(EmployeeType.DOCTOR); 
    employee.setSalary(10500); 
    employee.addRoom(23);
    employee.setOfficeLocation("ASDASDAS 4p,rom. 102"); 

    session.save(employee);
    transaction.commit();  
    session.close(); 

}
```

Here is my configuration :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory> 
     <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/mydb/xdb</property>
    <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">2</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>


     <mapping class="com.orm.project.model.Employee"/>
</session-factory>
```

Here is Employee.java :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
   public class Employee { 
@Id 
@Column(name = "id") 
@GeneratedValue
   private int id;

@Column(name = "firstName") 
   private String name;   

@Column(name = "lastName")
   private String surname;   

@Column(name = "salary")
   private int salary; 

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) 
@Column(name = "employee_type")
   private EmployeeType employeeType;  

@ElementCollection 
@CollectionTable(name="EMPLOYEE") 
@JoinColumn(name="ROOM_ID") 
@Column(name = "assigned_rooms")
   private List<Integer> assignedRooms = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

@Column(name = "office_location") 
    private String officeLocation; 

    // get + set methods
```

Finally here is error :

```
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE (id, employee_type, firstName,     
office_location, salary, lastName) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute     
statementatorg.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:72)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:492)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:197)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
at com.orm.project.App.fun(App.java:51)
at com.orm.project.App.main(App.java:27)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity   
constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10143 table: 
EMPLOYEE column: EMPLOYEE_ID
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
... 23 more
```

My questions are :

1. How to solve this ?.
2. Im using maven to build this project.It is possible to configure maven in this way to create database and all needed file in taget directory ?.I want have all project in way root directory.

Im really grateful for any help.

Best regards,

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be your generation strategy. Use sequences instead of @GeneratedValue. Like this:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="EMPLOYEE_GENERATOR",sequenceName="SEQ_EMPLOYEE",allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="EMPLOYEE_GENERATOR")
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help.Still the "same" error. :(

Comment: Do you have any means to verify if the sequence got created in the database? Since you have the property "hbm2ddl.auto" set to "update" there should be a warning in the log if the creation of the sequence failed on startup.

Comment: I'm sure it isn't.If you see on this log : 
http://pastebin.com/frEhJfpc you'll see that too.

Comment: Ok, looking at that log you clearly have a mapping problem. The message **NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10093 table: EMPLOYEE column: EMPLOYEE_ID** states that your ID column is called EMPLOYEE_ID, however, you are mapping: `@Column(name = "id")`. Try changing the name of the column you are mapping and see how it goes.

Comment: Yep, 
Now everythink is work ok :) 
Thx Kikin-Sama :)